# How to do Math Functions on Lists within a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math, nested-lists

I'm very new to python (using python3) and I'm trying to add numbers from one list to another list. The only problem is that the second list is a list of lists. For example:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

What I want is to, say, add 1 to each item in the first list and 2 to each item in the second, returning something like this:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

I tried this:

```
original_lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
trasposition_lst = [1, 2]
new_lst = [x+y for x,y in zip(original_lst, transposition_ls)]
print(new_lst)
```

When I do this, I get an error

> can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

This leads me to believe that I can't operate in this way on the lists as long as they are nested within another list. I want to do this operation without flattening the nested list. Is there a solution?

Comment: You might consider to change the title.

Comment: @user32185 what should I change it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A different approach than `numpy` that could work even for lists of different lengths is

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
c = [1, 2]
res = [[l + c[i] for l in lst[i]] for i in range(len(c))]
```

Answer (score 4):

One approach using `enumerate`

**Demo:**

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
print(  [[j+i for j in v] for i,v in enumerate(l, 1)] )
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `enumerate`:

```
l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
new_l = [[c+i for c in a] for i, a in enumerate(l, 1)]
```

Output:

```
[[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use numpy instead?

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
mul = np.array([1,2])
m = np.ones(mat.shape)
res = (m.T *mul).T + mat
```

Comment: Good answer although it seems like a lot of extra effort for this particular case with no added benefit.

Comment: Off course `numpy` is an overkill if you just need to work for this case. It becomes handy when you work with bigger arrays. Anyway I posted another answer that generalize the solution for lists of different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close with you original method. Just fell one step short.

**Small addition**

```
original_lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
transposition_lst = [1, 2]
new_lst = [[xx + y for xx in x] for x, y in zip(original_lst, transposition_lst)]
print(new_lst)
```

**Output**

```
[[2, 3, 4], [6, 7, 8]]
```

**Reasoning**

If you print your original zip it is easy to see the issue. Your original zip yielded this:

**In:**

```
original_lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
transposition_lst = [1, 2]
for x,y in zip(original_lst, transposition_lst):
    print(x, y)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3] 1
[4, 5, 6] 2
```

Now it is easy to see that you are trying to add an integer to a list (hence the error). Which python doesn't understand. if they were both integers it would add them or if they were both lists it would combine them.

To fix this you need to do one extra step with your code to add the integer to each value in the list. Hence the addition of the extra list comprehension in the solution above.